# Exclude folder from all projects using Directory.Build.props?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution of projects, each of which contains of folder "Previews".  I want this folder to always be excluded from my projects.

When I "Exclude From Project" through Visual Studio, the following is added to the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Previews\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="Previews\**" />
  <None Remove="Previews\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I remove that from the `.csproj` files, and add it to the `Directory.Build.props` file, it no longer excludes the file from VS.

I also tried using `"$(ProjectDir)\Previews\**"` and the complete path with no properties, neither of which worked.

How can this be achieved? It seems like it should be possible since VS can pick up on references declared, and many other project properties in the solution `.props` file.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue, Aze?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Instead**, you should use `Directory.Build.targets`.

Your operation is to overwrite the some items on MSBuild and that is the `.targets` file's function. It is imported at the bottom of the `csproj` file so that it can overwrite the items.(msbuild reads from the top to the bottom and take the last XML node as the final value).

**But** `.props` file is imported at the top of the `csproj` file and it is used as to define some new global properties. **Since** it imported at the top, it cannot be used as overwriting value operation and it is always overridden by properties under the main body of the csproj file.

**Besides**, you can [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order) to get the usage of the two files.

**Since** your `item remove` is overwriting operations, you should change the file into `Directory.Build.targets`.

**Note**: the two files are embedded into the main csproj file during build. So all the msbuild properties, items,.... can be used under the two files.

Answer (score 1):

Using [@Mr. Qian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878432/939634)'s answer, I was able to use `Directory.Build.targets` when `Directory.Build.props` didn't work.

For anyone looking to 'hide' specific files/globs in Visual Studio across a solution of projects, here is my `Directory.Build.targets` which excludes npm `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, and NuGet `packages.lock.json` files across all projects:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="*lock.json" />
        <Content Remove="package.json" />
        <None Remove="*lock.json" />
        <None Remove="package.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```